# Android - mediaPlayer.setWakeMode not working

Tags: android

This is my service class

```
public class BindService extends Service {
        IBinder mBinder=new MyBinder();
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        int firstPlayed = 0;

        public void seekTo(int progress) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
        }

        public int getCurrentPostion() {
            return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }

        public int getMax() {
            return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        }

        public class MyBinder extends Binder{
            BindService getService(){
                return BindService.this;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.azhar_itni_si_baat_hai);


        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return mBinder;
        }
        void start(){
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
    //        mediaPlayer.release();
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {
            mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        void pause(){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
}
```

I am using the code below which doesnt work

```
mediaplayer.setWakeMode()
mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
```

The Music stops after 30 secs after turning of the screen.

Comment: Looks like what you actually want is that the music keeps playing in the background ? right ? or you want the screen to remain on ? `setWakeMode()` is generally used for the latter feature.

Comment: Also, how do you start this service ? is it a `started` service ? or a `bound` service ?

Comment: it is a bounded service

Comment: and yes the audio is playing in background very well but the real problem is that I want to play the audio even when phone goes to sleep for which i am using setWakeMode

Comment: `setWakeMode()` will do no help in "playing in background". You need a `started` service. See the ans.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play music in the background, the best way would be to use `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app.html).

You can also achieve this using `Service` but in my opinion, that wont be as reliable as `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`.

To use `Service`, what you need is a started service (and not a bound service). You refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingStartedService#Creating_a_started_service) for that . And then make sure you return `START_REDILIVER_INTENT` inside the `onStartCommand()`.

The `onStartCommand()`'s return value will make sure that the if the service gets killed by the OS, the OS will start it as soon as possible with the same last intent that started the service initially.

**EDIT :**

Also, if you make your service a foreground service (as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingStartedService#Services)), then it will have much lesser chances of being killed.

Comment: I want to play music when the phone sleeps, that was the question

Comment: Did you try what I mentioned in the ans ? how do you think the OS works ? The Activity and fragments get killed by the OS if they are not in use. The Service on the other hand can work in the background. You do not need to set the wakeUpFlags to get it working in the background. The CPU wont sleep if it has somthing to do, and service is that 'something' that it does.

Comment: Then, a `bound` service is killed by the OS as soon as the its other end (the UI element mostly) gets killed, while the `started` service is not killed unless the OS is really low on resources. Even if a started service is killed, you can ask the OS to start it again.

Comment: What you want is that the your app's component that playse the music do not gets killed when the app is not in use. So a `started` service is what will help you in that.

Comment: If you think thats logical enough, you must go ahead and try rather than waiting for someone to post the exact code to be copied. Still the choice remains with you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it

Comment: But how to start service in background with the help of MediaBrowserServiceCompat? Please tell

Comment: That would be a long topic and the linked doc in the ans ( that is, [this one](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app.html)) explains the process.

Comment: Made an edit to the ans. And maybe you would want to try the normal `Service` approach first. It will take lesser time and might just fit your requirement.

Comment: I already told you everything you need to do. The changes in the code will like writting the `Service` completely myself. And  I am afraid I am busy for that.

Answer (score 0):

For android with long lasting background services android has made some updates due to battery and security concern.

For long lasting services user should get notified regarding more helpful information
and notification should be build with startForeground within onStartCommand. May be this will help someone it took my whole day to dig out.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
createNotificationChannel();
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
        0, notificationIntent, 0);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
        .setContentText(input)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build();

startForeground(1, notification);

//do heavy work on a background thread


//stopSelf();

return START_STICKY;
```

}